# ZFS showing free space, can not delete

Tags: linux, debian, zfs

I've got an old zfs pool (created 05-2012) that was running on debian 7.6 and had 26Gbytes free (out of 58Tbytes) as reported by df. I've just re-installed the os  (debian 8.7) and now the pool is showing as 0 bytes free in df but 1.04Tbyte "FREE" with zpool list.

I have 2 questions:

1) What is the difference between FREE in zpool list (=1.04Tbytes) and AVAIL in zfs list (=0) ?

2) Is there anything I can do to use this 1Tbyte free space ? I've deleted all the snapshots and this made no difference...

Thanks in advance.

```
% df -h /contentA
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
contentA         58T   58T     0 100% /contentA

% zpool list contentA
NAME       SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
contentA    65T  64.0T  1.04T     16.0E      -    98%  1.00x  ONLINE  -

% zfs list contentA
NAME       USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
contentA  58.0T      0  58.0T  /contentA

% uname -a
Linux myserver 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux

% cat /etc/debian_version 
8.7
```

Comment: Do you have any snapshots in the pool?  `zfs list -t all` (leave off the `contentA` because only the `contentA` filesystem itself matches that name and you won't see any snapshots if you include it in the command - at least that's how `zfs list ...` behaves on my copy of Solaris 11...)

Answer (score 1):

From the `zfs(8)` man page, `available` means:

```
The amount of space available to the dataset and all its children,
assuming that there is no other activity in the pool. Because space
is shared within a pool, availability can be limited by any number of
factors, including physical pool size,  quotas, reservations, or other
datasets within the pool.
```

Generally speaking, the first place to look for differences is stuff outside of that dataset, such as a reservation set on a different dataset in the same pool.

However, from your post it looks like the dataset you ran `list` against might be the root dataset for your pool, which should account for all of the other sub-datasets on there. There are some cases where your pool configuration can cause differences like this, as detailed in the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29007/gbbti.html).

However (again), these usually apply to space that will be required for redundancy and metadata storage in the event that your logical data size expands (i.e. mirrored pools show half as much `available` space as `free` space, since every byte you write to the dataset has to be copied to two places). Since your dataset's `available` is zero, obviously this is not simply accounting for predicted overhead of future writes.

That brings me to the final explanation. ZFS has a safety mechanism built into its space accounting to prevent users from filling a pool beyond 63/64ths full (which strikes me as being incredibly close to the proportions in your case, and therefore almost certainly the limit you're hitting). Because ZFS always requires new space to make modifications to on-disk state (because of copy-on-write), if you went beyond that limit it's possible that the pool would no longer be able to delete things to free up space for new writes, causing it to become read-only -- **permanently**. Although it may be possible to patch ZFS or change a tunable to bypass the limit, I would not recommend it!

Comment: Do you have a link to that 63/64 thing? That sounds interesting.

Comment: @user121391 I don't know if it's in the documentation anywhere, but the limits are defined here in the code (for ZFS on Linux): https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/blob/master/include/sys/dsl_synctask.h

Comment: @Dan It's the same in the OpenSolaris source at Illumos.org:  http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/uts/common/fs/zfs/sys/dsl_synctask.h  So it's likely the same in all ZFS implementations.

Comment: Yep, I was just pointing to the Linux version since the question mentioned Debian.

Comment: @AndrewHenle , Dan: Thanks for both links!